# Sox cannot determine type of file

Tags: node.js, express, multer, sox

I'm using node js and express with sox node bindings. I have a temporary uploaded file that I need to identify, but since the file does not have an extension, SoX gives me this error:

```
sox.identify(file, function(err, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw(err)
    }
});
```

> sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of file
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\Media\temp\riqDeq15151sf14FWa

I'm using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for saving the uploaded file temporarily. Is there anyway to have SoX identify the file even though it doesn't have an extension?

Comment: Sox doesn't rely on extensions to identify files, so it's probably the file itself that's either broken, or it's in a format that Sox doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Sox file type is not determined with the Extension of the file. Review your file to check whether it is having an appropriate format or whether the file is downloaded correctly.

Review this page from developers on Sox Format support - http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html